# How can I change product name to product sku in qtyincrements.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, template

On our item page we have a block that says "product name is available for purchase in increments of amount" I would like to change product name to product sku. Here is how the original code looks ...

```
<?php if ($this->getProductQtyIncrements()) : ?>
<div class="product-pricing">
    <?php echo $this->__('%s is available for purchase in increments of %s', $this->getProductName(), $this->getProductQtyIncrements()) ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I tried changing `$this->getProductName()` to `$this->getProductSku()` or to `$this->getSku()` and nothing shows up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Mage_CatalogInventory_Block_Qtyincrements` is no function that can do this.

This schould work:

```
Mage::registry('current_product')->getSku()
```

**Edit:** just for information why `$this->getProductName()` works:

```
/**
 * Retrieve current product object
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
protected function _getProduct()
{
    return Mage::registry('current_product');
}

/**
 * Retrieve current product name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductName()
{
    return $this->_getProduct()->getName();
}
```